# Nested nsurl dataTaskWithRequest but after the completion handler called

Tags: objective-c, api, thread-safety, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I have this part of code and it was work with "NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest" and they was having a dispatch and have the both API call in it with no issues, however since i am moving to "NSURLSession" and i would to call the next API after the first one response inside the completionHandler, do i need tho add any type of dispatches for the second API call?

```
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ dispatch was here

    __block NSString* url = @"www.google.com";
    [[LoaderService get] getRequestFrom:url completionHandler:^(TcHttpJSONResponse *response) { // first Call
        if (!response.success) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                failBlock();
            });
            return;
        }
        
        url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.google.com/drive"];
        [[LoaderService get] getRequestFrom:url completionHandler:^(TcHttpJSONResponse *response) { // second Call
            if (!response.success) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    failBlock();
                });
                return;
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                successBlock(transactionsArray);
            });
        }];
    }];
//    }]; //end of dispatch
```

in LoaderService

```
- (void)getRequestFrom:(NSString *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(TcHttpJSONResponse *response))completionHandler {
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:[TcHttpHelper getRequestFromUrlWithAuthorizationToken:url token:[self getAuthToken]]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,  NSError *error) {
        completionHandler([[TcHttpJSONResponse alloc] initWithResponse:data urlResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response error:error]);
    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: I did not check all your code but in principle what you try to do should work no problem.

Comment: @skaak yes it works, but is this right? do i need to add "dispatch_async" before the second, third, etc http call as it's inside the completionHandler of the previous call?

Comment: Hi - no you can message it anytime and on any thread. ```NSURLSession.currentSession dataTask...``` and ```NSURLSession.currentSession downloadTask...``` are your two goto solutions for simple asynchronous download. You can message them from anywhere as all they do is schedule a new task which will then execute on another thread and message you when done.

Comment: If you want to update UI when done you should worry about dispatching on the main thread in the completion handler.

Comment: for the nested call will be many dispatcher for updating the UI and this will not be a good looking code, i fixed this by using delegateQueue when i created the session, so the whole completion handler is on the main thread now.
Many thanks for the help @skaak

Comment: Good to hear - thing of beauty Omar! Coding is like art .... and it is nice being a very small part of your lovely painting.